# Can this be called a matrix diagonalization/uniqueness of diagonalization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, classical-mechanics, symmetric-matrices

I'm a physics undergrad and am studying small osciallations from Goldstien's Classical Mecahnics. We end up having to solve a system governed by the eigenvalue equation:
$$ \boldsymbol{V \vec{a}}  = \omega^2 \boldsymbol{ T  \vec{a}}= \lambda \boldsymbol{T  \vec{a}} $$
where V  and  T are real symmetric matrices with real eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ and eigenvectors $\vec{a_k}$.

We are left with the equations,

$$ \boldsymbol{\tilde{A} T A  = I} $$
$$ \boldsymbol{\tilde{A} V A  = \lambda} $$
where $A$ is a square matrix with the eigenvectors as its columns and $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues as the diagonal elements. Also **the components of the eigenvectors are made to be real**

The book concludes from the final equation,

> Blockquote The final equation states that a congruence transformation of V by A changes it into a diagonal matrix whose elements are the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ , the equation admits the solutions, $$ | V - \lambda I | = 0 $$ where the matrix containing the eigenvectors diagonalizes V.

But this seems like now we are solving the eigenvalue problem $$ V \vec{a} = \lambda \vec{a}  $$I didn't seem to find any sound justifications to support this sudden conclusion . Is this because of some sort of uniqueness of diagonalization, or is there something else I'm missing.